# angular - catch new line(\n) from java

Tags: java, angularjs

I am having a problem `catching` or detecting a `new line`(`\n`) insert from my server side(java servlet) in my angular `ng-repeat`.

server side:

```
StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
name.append(getFirst(id)); //id - @param 
name.append("\n"); //new line
name.append(getLast(id)); //id - @param
```

But on my client side, in my `ng-repeat`:

`{{reporter.name}}` `//jhon doe`
instead of:

jhon

doe
if there is more code needed I will post it.

Comment: can you try "<br/>" instead of "\n".

Comment: in my server side?

Comment: while rendering HTML would treat it as a regular whitespace character and collapse all whitespaces to a single whitespace, you can either use <pre> to display it as it is, or convert it to <br>

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas yeah on the server side, only if you are not planning to use it anywhere else other than in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the css style for your requirement:

```
white-space: pre|pre-line|pre-wrap;

pre     - Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will only wrap on line breaks. Acts like the <pre> tag in HTML   
pre-line - Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks    
pre-wrap    Whitespace is preserved by the browser. Text will wrap when necessary, and on line breaks
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example111-production</title>
  

  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  
  <style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>

  
</head>
<body ng-app="sanitizeExample">
       <script>
         angular.module('sanitizeExample', [])
           .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
             $scope.friends = [
    {name:'John\nDoe', age:25, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Jessie\nSimpson', age:30, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Johanna\nLN', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Joy\nLN', age:15, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Mary\nLN', age:28, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Peter\nLN', age:95, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Sebastian\nLN', age:50, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Erika\nLN', age:27, gender:'girl'},
    {name:'Patrick\nLN', age:40, gender:'boy'},
    {name:'Samantha\nLN', age:60, gender:'girl'}
  ];
             
           }]);
           
          
     </script>
     <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
       <table
   class="table-bordered">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Age</th>
     <th>Gender</th>
    
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="friend in friends">
     <td style="white-space: pre;">{{friend.name}}</td>
     <td>{{friend.age}}</td>
     <td>{{friend.gender}}</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
       </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace all \n with < br>, do something like this

    `str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');`

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in `<pre>` tag

```
<pre>{{reporter.name}}</pre>
```

Comment: Trying and postinf the result.